# VBS appending a Word Document

Tags: foreach, vbscript

I have some MS Word files in a folder,  and I need to append a specific text at the beginning of each Word document. I created a function add_title(whatever) to accomplish my task. I call the function inside a for loop, but it only appends the text to the first file.

```
Function add_title(whatever)
wdStory = 6
wdMove = 0
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = FALSE
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\A\D\P\"+whatever)
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.HomeKey wdStory, wdMove
objSelection.TypeText "This text was appended to an existing Word document."
objSelection.TypeText(Chr(11))
objSelection.TypeText "Management"
objDoc.Saved = TRUE
objWord.Quit
End Function

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Users\A\D\P"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each file in colFiles
    add_title(file.Name)
    MsgBox "Completed"  

Next
```

Comment: @user692942 thanks for the heads-up; I made a few changes to the code you posted and it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes, following the link above, and it all works now:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\A\D\P")
objWord.Visible = False
wdStory = 6
wdMove = 0
counter = 0
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    if objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.path) = "docx" then
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(objFile.path)
    counter= counter +1
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
    objSelection.Font.Size = "10"
    objSelection.HomeKey wdStory, wdMove
    objSelection.TypeText "This text was appended to an existing Word document."
    objSelection.TypeText(Chr(11))
    objSelection.TypeText "Management"
    objSelection.Delete
    objDoc.SaveAs objFSO.BuildPath("C:\Users\A\D\P",objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile.path) 
    &".docx")
    objDoc.Close
    MsgBox counter & " File has been appended successfully!"
end if

 Next
```